# BibTex adding arXiv number and doi with amsplain

Tags: bibtex, amsplain

Currently, I am using bibTex and amsplain. My problem is the following: I would like to add the arXiv number of a reference if it is given in the bib. file.
Moreover, I would like to add the DOI number, but only for one specific reference.

As an exemple, in my bib.tex file (test.bib) I have for example this:

---

```
 @ARTICLE{2017arXiv170200666D,
 author = {{D{\'{\i}}az Ramos}, A.},
 title = "{Spectral sequences via examples}",
 journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
 archivePrefix = "arXiv",
 eprint = {1702.00666},
 primaryClass = "math.AT",
 keywords = {Mathematics - Algebraic Topology, 55T},
 year = 2017,
 month = feb,
 adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv170200666D},
 adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
 }
```

and

```
 @article {MR0240167,
 AUTHOR = {Gerstenhaber, Murray},
 TITLE = {On the deformation of rings and algebras. {III}},
 JOURNAL = {Ann. of Math. (2)},     
 FJOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics. Second Series},
 VOLUME = {88},
 YEAR = {1968},
 PAGES = {1--34},
 ISSN = {0003-486X},
 MRCLASS = {18.20},
 MRNUMBER = {0240167},
 MRREVIEWER = {D. W. Knudson},
 DOI = {10.2307/1970553},
 URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970553},
 }
```

In my .tex file I have the following:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}    
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
 \usepackage{lmodern}    
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

 \begin{document}

 \cite{2017arXiv170200666D,MR0240167}    

 \bibliographystyle{amsplain}    
 \bibliography{test}

 \end{document}
```

If I compile this with amsplain, I get for the first entry:

> A. Díaz Ramos, Spectral sequences via examples, ArXiv e-prints (2017).

However, I would prefer if the arXiv number was given explicitly, i.e.

> A. Díaz Ramos, Spectral sequences via examples, arXiv:1702.00666 (2017).

For the second example, I get:

> Murray Gerstenhaber, On the deformation of rings and algebras. II, Ann. of Math. 84 (1966), 1–19.
>   MR 0207793

I would prefer to have something like this:

> Murray Gerstenhaber, On the deformation of rings and algebras. II, Ann. of Math. 84 (1966), 1–19,
>   MR 0207793, DOI:10.2307/1970553.

Preferentially, I would like to have the DOI only for this specific .bib entry, not for the other .bib entries. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.